# how to find out which Python is called when I run pytest via Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I am running pytest on a Jenkins machine; although I am not sure which Python it is actually running.

The machine is running OSX; and I did install various libraries (like numpy and others), on top of another Python install via Brew, so I keep things separated.

When I run the commands from console; I specify `python2.6 -m pytest mytest.py`, which works, but when I run the same via shell in Jenkins, it fail, because it can't find the right libraries (which are the extra libraries I did install, after installing Python via Brew).

Is there a way to know what is Jenkins using, so I can force it to run the correct python binary, which has access to my extra libraries?

Comment: What about `which python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `sys` module

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Comment: Works; also it seems that Jenkins is not affected by .bash_profile somehow; since PYTHONPATH was not set; while if I open a terminal window, I can see that it is clearly set

Answer (score 0):

You can use `which python` to find which python Jenkins use.
You can use `ABSPATH/OF/python` to run your `pytest`